# Can you add clauses in a where block conditionally when using Squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, squeel

To start, I'm using Rails v3.2.9 with Squeel 1.0.13 and here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to search for a client using any of three pieces of identifying information - name, date of birth (dob), and social insurance number (sin). The result set must include any record that has any of the identifier - an OR of the conditions. I have done this in Squeel before and it would look something like:

```
scope :by_any, ->(sin, name, dob){ where{(client.sin == "#{sin}") | (client.name =~ "%#{name}%") | (client.dob == "#{dob}")} }
```

This works fine as long as I provide all of the identifiers. But what if I only have a name? The above scope results in:

```
SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE ((("clients"."sin" IS NULL OR "clients"."name" ILIKE '%John Doe%') OR "clients"."dob" IS NULL))
```

This includes the set of clients where sin is null and the set of clients where dob is null along with the requested set of clients with a name like 'John Doe'.

So enter my attempt to conditionally add clauses to the `where` block. At first, I tried to check the values using the nil? method:

```
def self.by_any (sin, name, dob)
  where do
    (clients.sin == "#{sin}" unless sin.nil?) |
    (clients.name =~ "%#{name}" unless name.nil?) |
    (clients.dob == "#{dob}" unless dob.nil?)
  end
```

which results in:

```
SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE ('t')
```

raising many other questions, like what's the deal with that 't', but that's a tangent.

Short of writing the where clause for each permutation, is there a way I can conditionally add  clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this isn't the prettiest thing ever, but it does what you're after.

```
def self.by_any(sin, name, dob)
  where do
    [
      sin.presence && clients.sin == "#{sin}",
      name.presence && clients.name =~ "%#{name}",
      dob.presence && clients.dob == "#{dob}"
    ].compact.reduce(:|)
    # compact to remove the nils, reduce to combine the cases with |
  end
end
```

Basically, `[a, b, c].reduce(:f)` returns `(a.f(b)).f(c)`. In this case `f`, the method invoked, is the pipe, so we get `(a.|(b)).|(c)` which, in less confusing notation, is `(a | b) | c`.

It works because, in Squeel, the predicate operators (`==`, `=~`, and so on) return a `Predicate` node, so we can construct them independently before joining them with `|`.

In the case where all three are `nil`, it returns all records.

Comment: Prettier that what I actually came up with. Stole a bit from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045823/how-do-i-write-a-union-chain-with-activerelation) to come up with my answer, but I think I like your better. I'll have to out compact and reduce.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `reduce` - I will be using this again in the future.

Comment: I get a "syntax error, unexpected modifier_if, expecting ']'" right before the if statement in array creation loop? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Yeah this was blatantly wrong, sorry. You can't use the `if`s like that at all. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Andy amazing! Thank you for the help, but more importantly the amazing speed of updating the solution. I would have never figured it out; still learning Ruby. Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

After eventually finding [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045823/how-do-i-write-a-union-chain-with-activerelation), I cannibalized @bradgonesurfing 's *alternate pattern* to come to this solution:

```
def self.by_any (sin, name, dob)
  queries = Array.new
  queries << self.by_sin(sin) unless sin.nil?
  queries << self.by_name(name) unless name.nil?
  queries << self.by_dob(dob) unless dob.nil?

  self.where do
    queries = queries.map { |q| id.in q.select{id} }
    queries.inject { |s, i| s | i }
  end
end
```

where `self.by_sin`, `self.by_name`, and `self.by_dob` are simple scopes with filters. This produces something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients 
WHERE clients.id IN (<subquery for sin>) 
   OR clients.id IN (<subquery for name>) 
   OR clients.id IN (<subquery for dob>)
```

where the subqueries are only include if their associated value is not nil.

This effectively allows me to union the appropriate scopes together as an ActiveRecord::Relation.