# How would you do this Rails sub-query using Squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, squeel

I want to restructure the query below using Squeel. I'd like to do this so that I can chain the operators in it and re-use the logic in the different parts of the query.

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT 
    users.*,
    users.computed_metric,
    users.age_in_seconds,
    ( users.computed_metric / age_in_seconds) as compound_computed_metric
    from
    (
      select
        users.*,
        (users.id *2 ) as computed_metric,
        (extract(epoch from now()) - extract(epoch from users.created_at) ) as age_in_seconds
        from users
    ) as users")
```

The query has to all operate in the DB and should not be a hybrid Ruby solution since it has to order and slice millions of records.

I've set the problem up so that it should run against a normal `user` table and so that you can play with the alternatives to it.

### Restrictions on an acceptable answer

- the query should return a `User` object with all the normal attributes
- each user object should also include `extra_metric_we_care_about`, `age_in_seconds` and `compound_computed_metric`
- the query should not duplicate any logic by just printing out a string in multiple places - I want to avoid doing the same thing twice
- [updated] The query should all be do-able in the DB so that a result set that may consist of millions of records can be ordered and sliced in the DB before returning to Rails
- [updated] The solution should work for a Postgres DB

### Example of the type of solution I'd like

The solution below doesn't work but it shows the type of elegance that I'm hoping to achieve

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# this doesn't work - it just illustrates what I want to achieve

  def self.w_all_additional_metrics
    select{ ['*', 
              computed_metric, 
              age_in_seconds, 
              (computed_metric / age_in_seconds).as(compound_computed_metric)] 
      }.from{ User.w.compound_computed_metric.w_age_in_seconds }
  end

  def self.w_computed_metric
    where{ '(id *2 ) as computed_metric' }
  end

  def self.w_age_in_seconds
    where{ '(extract(epoch from now()) - extract(epoch from created_at) ) as age_in_seconds' }
  end
end
```

#### You should be able to run this against your existing database

*Please note that I've somewhat contrived the problem so that you can use your existing `User` class and play with it in your console.*

### EDIT

1. The DB I'm using is Postgres.
2. I'm not sure I made it 100% clear that the query should all execute in the DB. It can't be a hybrid answer were some of the logic is essentially done in Rails. This is important since I want to be able to order and slice millions of records using the computed columns.

Comment: Just lobbing softballs my way... how hard could solving this be... ugh! The race is on to get the bounty!

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually possible without violating your third restriction on an acceptable answer. In case you haven't already had a look, I've taken steps towards something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412142/ranking-results-with-complex-conditions-using-rails-and-squeel) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274910/multiple-joins-to-the-same-model-using-multiple-belongs-to-associations).

Comment: I don't get it. What you described can be simply solved without any fancy squeel chaining. There is no need to use a sub-query. The compound_computed_metric is calculated against each row in the table, and there is no aggregation.

Comment: @wanghq - that would be great if it is the case. Could you write the query that achieves that? erroric - I'll take a look, ty

Comment: @erroric - it's avoiding the duplicated SQL (and DB work) that's hard. I don't think it fits any of the other two examples that you posted although you're clearly thinking along the same lines as me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have 2 sulutions in your case. My database is mysql, and I simplify your code for demo, I think you can extend it.

The first is Squeel way, I mixed "sift" in Squeel and "from" in ActiveRecord Query.
I installed postgresql and tested my solution just now, It seems hardly to use "squeel" and "epoch from" together, but I found an alternative way in postgresql, it called "date_part". I also modified the sql and reduced the duplications of calculation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base           
  sifter :w_computed_metric do
    (id * 2).as(computed_metric)
  end

  sifter :w_age_in_seconds do
    (date_part('epoch' , now.func) - date_part('epoch', created_at)).as(age_in_seconds)
  end

  sifter :w_compound_computed_metric do
    (computed_metric / age_in_seconds).as(compound_computed_metric)
  end

  def self.subquery
    select{['*', sift(w_computed_metric) , sift(w_age_in_seconds)]}
  end

  def self.w_all_additional_metrics
    select{['*', sift(w_compound_computed_metric)]}.from("(#{subquery.to_sql}) users")
  end      
end
```

It produced the sql:

```
SELECT *, "users"."computed_metric" / "users"."age_in_seconds" AS compound_computed_metric 
FROM (SELECT *, 
             "users"."id" * 2 AS computed_metric, 
             date_part('epoch', now()) - date_part('epoch', "users"."created_at") AS age_in_seconds FROM "users" 
     ) users
```

You can test it using the console:

```
> User.w_all_additional_metrics.first.computed_metric
=> "2"
> User.w_all_additional_metrics.first.age_in_seconds
=> "633.136693954468"
> User.w_all_additional_metrics.first.compound_computed_metric
=> "0.00315887551471441"
```

The second is ActiveRecord way, because your sql is not very complicate, so you can chain it in ActiveRecord Query, it's enough with some scopes :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :w_computed_metric, proc { select('id*2 as computed_metric') }
  scope :w_age_in_seconds, proc { select('extract (epoch from (now()-created_at)) as age_in_seconds') }
  scope :w_compound_computed_metric, proc { select('computed_metric/age_in_seconds as compound_computed_metric') }

  def self.subquery
    select('*').w_computed_metric.w_age_in_seconds
  end

  def self.w_all_additional_metrics
    subquery.w_compound_computed_metric.from("(#{subquery.to_sql}) users")
  end
end
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  *, id*2 as computed_metric, 
  extract (epoch from (now()-created_at)) as age_in_seconds, 
  computed_metric / age_in_seconds as compound_computed_metric
FROM (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      id*2 as computed_metric, 
      extract (epoch from (now()-created_at)) as age_in_seconds 
    FROM 
      "users" 
    ) users 
ORDER BY compound_computed_metric DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Hope it meets your requirement :)

Comment: Thank you for this, your answer's very interesting. Unfortunately though I was looking to solve this in Sqeel rather than Sequel though it was interesting to discover that Sequel existed as I hadn't heard of it before!

Comment: I am very sorry, I read "squeel" to "sequel".... , I have read the document of squeel and will update the answer.

Comment: I'm really impressed with this. I haven't managed to make the Squeel version work just yet but am still playing with it to see if I can. I really like your pure AR version however I've got a question. I've put the SQL that it generates into your answer (feel free to delete it but comments get crunched). If you notice in the SQL the computations are actually done twice - once in the subquery and then once in the super-query. Is it possible to reduce them to only happening once to save on computation? If you can do it cleanly without the computational duplication the points are yours.

Comment: I think that the Squeel query has the same problem ast he other one - in postgres it needs the extract(epoch) function to work. Would be very interested if you knew how to add that into the Squeel

Comment: Hi, I updated the squeel solution again, please check it again :)

Comment: Wow. I'm really impressed. I didn't think I was going to get an answer that works but as far as I can tell this does exactly what I was hoping for. Great work. Also can you ping me via email - petenixey at gmail. I'd value staying in touch.

Comment: Hi, I sent an email to you. I notice your name is peternixey, but email is petenixey. Is it correct?

Comment: I can't believe how slick this is. Bigxiang you are my hero! One of the keys to this solution is using the alias of 'users' for the subquery in the `from` clause. Again, FANTASTIC!

Comment: And one more thing - you resolved the issue of `extract(epoch from ...)` that caused all sorts of grief for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's very probably that I am totally wrong. I feel you simplify your problem too much in order to let others understand it. Since I can't give this well-formatted code in a comment, I input the answer here.

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    users.computed_metric,
    users.age_in_seconds,
    ( users.computed_metric / age_in_seconds) as compound_computed_metric
    from
    (
      select
        users.*,
        (users.id *2 ) as computed_metric,
        (extract(epoch from now()) - extract(epoch from users.created_at) ) as age_in_seconds
        from users
    ) as users
```

Below SQL is equivalent to your above SQL. That's why I say the sub-query is not necessary.

```
select
  users.*,
  (users.id *2 ) as computed_metric,
  (extract(epoch from now()) - extract(epoch from users.created_at) ) as age_in_seconds,
  computed_metric/age_in_seconds as compound_computed_metric
  from users
```

If that's right, then the compound_computed_metric can be calculated in below way. No custom query is needed.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def compound_computed_metric
    computed_metric/age_in_seconds
  end
  def computed_metric
    self.id * 2
  end
  def age_in_seconds
    Time.now - self.created_at
  end
end

1.9.3p327 :001 > u = User.first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "spider", created_at: "2013-08-10 04:29:35", updated_at: "2013-08-10 04:29:35">
1.9.3p327 :002 > u.compound_computed_metric
 => 1.5815278998954843e-05
1.9.3p327 :003 > u.age_in_seconds
 => 126471.981447
1.9.3p327 :004 > u.computed_metric
 => 2
```

Comment: Hi Wang, my apologies. In the original SQL I forgot to request the compound metric and age in seconds in addition to the compound computed metric. You're right, I oversimplified it. I've just updated the question to include the request for both of them in the original SQL. Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Still feel the subquery is not necessary.

Comment: Did you manage to make that work because I got the following errors: `ERROR:  column "computed_metric" does not exist
LINE 5:   computed_metric/age_in_seconds as compound_computed_metric` - I don't think you can use a computed column a second time in a query (I fixed some syntactic errors in your answer btw). Also thank you for your time on this

Comment: This question shows the issue on re-using columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query. hence the sub-query!

Comment: which SQL database do you use? I used the default sqlite for experiment and have no problem doing the operations as I showed above (see console output).

Comment: I was using Postgres - there seemed to be a few extraneous commas which were making things fail. BTW I'm sorry that I screwed up with the bounty. I didn't really know how it was going to work so I'm going to create a new bounty and split it between you and @erroric (if I can figure out how)

Answer (score 1):

Let's preface this with it's not the answer you are looking for...

Now, with that out of the way, here is what I tried and how it relates to the two links I posted in the comments of the question.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # self-referential association - more on this later
  belongs_to :myself, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :id

  scope :w_computed_metric, ->() { select{[id, (id *2).as(computed_metric)]} }
  scope :w_age_in_seconds,  ->() { select{[id, (extract('epoch from now()') - extract('epoch from users.created_at')).as(age_in_seconds)]} }
  scope :w_default_attributes, ->() { select{`*`} }

  def self.compound_metric
    scope = User.w_default_attributes.select{(b.age_in_seconds / a.computed_metric).as(compound_metric)}
    scope = scope.joins{"inner join (" + User.w_computed_metric.to_sql + ") as a on a.id = users.id"}
    scope = scope.joins{"inner join (" + User.w_age_in_seconds.to_sql + ") as b on b.id = users.id"}
  end

  sifter :sift_computed_metric do
    (id * 2).as(computed_metric)
  end

  sifter :sift_age_in_seconds do
    (extract(`epoch from now()`) - extract(`epoch from users.created_at`)).as(age_in_seconds)
  end

  def self.using_sifters_in_select
    User.w_default_attributes.joins{myself}.select{[(myself.sift :sift_computed_metric), (myself.sift :sift_age_in_seconds)]}
  end

  def self.using_from
    scope = User.w_default_attributes
    scope = scope.select{[(age_in_seconds / computed_metric).as(compound_metric)]}
    scope = scope.from{User.w_computed_metric.w_age_in_seconds}
  end
end
```

So, running `User.compound_metric` in console will yield the results you are looking for - a `User` object with the additional attributes: `computed_metric`, `age_in_seconds`, and `compound_metric`. Unfortunately, this violates the third constraint you placed on an acceptable answer. Oh well...

I also tried a few other things (as you can see from above):

First point of note is the self-referential association, which I'm quite proud of - even though it doesn't get us to where we want to go.

```
belongs_to :myself, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :id
```

This nifty piece of code lets you access the same object through a join. Why is this important? Well, Squeel will only allow you to access associations through the `joins{}` method unless you pass it a string of SQL. This lets us use the `sifter`s feature of Squeel - in this case not to filter the results, rather to include *aggregate* columns from the db and let Squeel do the heavy lifting of aliasing and joining the statements. You can test it with the

```
def self.using_sifters_in_select
  User.w_default_attributes.joins{myself}.select{[(myself.sift :sift_computed_metric), (myself.sift :sift_age_in_seconds)]}
end
```

The beauty of sifters to acheive this is the chainability and syntatic sugar - it is very flat and readable.

The last bit I tried playing with is `.from{}`. Before this question, I didn't even know it existed. I was soooo excited with the possibility that I had missed something so simple as including a source for a query (in this case a sub-select). Testing with using_from

```
def self.using_from
    scope = User.w_default_attributes
    scope = scope.select{[(age_in_seconds / computed_metric).as(compound_metric)]}
    scope = scope.from{User.w_computed_metric.w_age_in_seconds}
end
```

results in a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::SelectManager
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:28:in `rescue in visit'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:348:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_JoinSource'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:21:in `visit'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:139:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `map'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:21:in `visit'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  from /home/prg10itd/projects/arel/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in `accept'
```

(and yes, I'm testing against a local copy of the Arel and Squeel). I'm not familiar enough with the internal workings of Arel to resolve the issue without further effort (and most likely a fork of Arel). It does appear that Squeel just passes the `from{}` method to the Arel `from()` method without doing anything (beyond the rest of the magic that is Squeel).

So where does that leave us? A solution that works, but is not as nice and elegant as I wish it was - but maybe someone else can leverage this to a better solution.

PS - this is with Rails v3.2.13 and the respective version of Arel. The source for Rails v4 and Arel are quite different and not tested for this.

Comment: Hi Erroric and apologies for taking so long to reply to your excellent answer. I believe I have hit the same error as you on the `from` method before and I *think* it's something to do with a gem incompatibility. Your answer was really interesting in that it took me towards trying to discover what sifters are (which I've never previously known) and also gave me a good way to look at things differently. I've upvoted it and am also happy to upvote any comments. Thank you